# Alerting Special Characters using jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, alert

How do i display a string with Special Characters like € in a Javascript/jQuery alert?

eg: I want to display a message box with "The Price is €10"

But when i use the below code:

```
alert("The Price is &euro;10");
```

The Output shown in the message box is `"The Price is &euro;10"`, I want my output to be `"The Price is €10"`.

Can some help me with this please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: drop the &euro; and use utf8 for your whole project

Comment: You don't need jQuery for this. alert() is pure Javascript.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/661524/122005

Comment: what if im going to alert this character - å

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use this as the alert. Works fine for me.

```
alert(' The Price is \u20AC 10');
```

The description is here : http://leftlogic.com/projects/entity-lookup/

Comment: What is the UTF8 for character å

Comment: Try alert(' The Price is \u00E5 10'); And please have a look at the link I gave in my answer. just type 'a' and it will show all the related characters

Comment: Thanks alot i found it - alert(' The Price is \u00E5 10');

Comment: Broken link :( d

Comment: The link is indeed broken, try this table as reference instead https://www.utf8-chartable.de/.
Simply replace the U+0008 by \u0008 or U+00A9 by \u00A9, for example.

Answer (score 10):

The native `alert` method does not decode HTML encoded entities.

But browsers do while rendering HTML. One hack is to create a HTML element with the specific text as its `innerHTML` (so it does the character processing), then get back its `text` property and alerting it out.

```
function alertSpecial(msg) {
    msg = $('<span/>').html(msg).text();
    alert(msg);
}
alertSpecial('The Price is &euro;10');
```

This will work for all &xxx characters that the browser can display, without needing to find out the character code for each special character you may want to use.

Comment: Nice! That did the trick for me. I was geting a json response with encoded html characters in a string from an API where i can't modify the output to UTF8.

Comment: An absolutely honourable response. This is the only workaround to properly show UTF-8 special characters and emojis in alert() functions retrieved from server-side AJAX responses sent as UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

Check :

```
alert("The Price is \u20AC 10");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Nseum/

[Unicode Character 'EURO SIGN' (U+20AC)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20ac/index.htm)