# dealing with special character encoding from / to html

Tags: c#, html

I am using a Rest service (asp.net core) which returns a string to the caller . The caller then is supposed to visualize that string on a html page, using a javascript "alert" function.
If the Rest service  returns a string  containing the "è" special character , the "alert" function always translates the "è" as a "&#xE8" sequence. Is there anything I can do to fix the situation ? 
If I inspect my razor code right before the alert call, to see what the string contains , I always find the right character ("è") which makes me think the problem is generated by the alert call .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alerting Special Characters using jQuery/JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622769/alerting-special-characters-using-jquery-javascript)

Comment: I tried the exposed solution . Nothing has changed

Comment: You probably have to replace characters like è manually with their unicode representation, `\u00e9` for é, also did you set the html charset to utf-8?